# Triangulo Alfabetico - Python

Tags: python

Estou com um exercicio onde, o enunciando informa o seguinte:

O alfabeto latino é composto por letras, começando em 'A' e encerrando em 'Z'. São vinte e seis caracteres diferentes,
se desconsiderarmos as acentuações e as diferenças entre letras maiúsculas e minúsculas.

Harry, um garoto muito estudioso, percebeu que é possível inclusive desenhar usando letras. Em um dos desenhos,
Harry escreve na primeira linha de uma folha o primeiro caractere do alfabeto, na segunda linha escreve duas vezes o segundo caractere,
na terceira linha escreve três vezes o terceiro caractere e assim por diante. Harry percebeu que com isso consegue formar um triângulo alfabético, semelhante ao visto na Figura 1.

Como Harry precisa estudar para realizar uma prova de programação (que para ele também é uma forma de magia!),
pediu para você ajudá-lo a automatizar os desenhos de "triângulos alfabéticos", criando um programa que receba
como entrada um número inteiro N (1 <= N <= 26) e que desenhe um triângulo com exatas N linhas, seguindo a mesma estratégia descrita no texto.

ENTRADA

Um número inteiro N (1 <= N <= 26).

SAÍDA

Um triângulo alfabético com exatas N linhas e com a mesma estratégia de construção mencionada no texto.
Note que as letras são sempre maiúsculas.

[image: EXEMPLOS]

O que fiz ate agora de codigo foi:

```
n = int(input())
x = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
x1 = []
for i in range(1, n+1):
    x1 = x.copy()
    print(f'{x1}')
```

Porem nao consigo extrair da list e imprimir a quantidade que e informado.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olha, você precisa apenas da variável de quantidade, a lista do alfabeto e um for para percorrer a lista e exibir a letra ao mesmo tempo. Fica assim:

```
vezes = int(input("Vezes: "))


alfabeto = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']


for i in range(vezes):
    print(alfabeto[i]*(i+1))
```

Desse jeito, digitando **4**, por exemplo, o resultado seria:

*>>A
BB
CCC
DDDD*

Explicando o código, ele funciona assim -> definida a quantidade de vezes, você já sabe o lugar de cada letra no alfabeto, então, alfabeto[0] = 'A', alfabeto[1] = 'B', e assim vai. Logo, você só precisa acessar a letra e imprimir ela na tela. No Python, é possível multiplicar uma variável **string**, então no **for** do código quando está na letra **'A' (alfabeto[0])**, i = 0, você quer que 'A' apareça 1 vez, então, multiplica por 1 (i+1), para 'B'(alfabeto[1]), i = 1, multiplica por 2 (i+1), e vai indo.

É isso... xD

Comment: Muito obrigado! Tenho sempre dúvidas quando se refere a lista no python.

Answer (score -3):

Olha, tem uma outra forma de se fazer o que você deseja, implementando o laço while, da seguinte forma:

```
entrada = int(input())

contador = 1
n = 65

while (entrada < 1 or entrada > 26):
  entrada = int(input())

while contador <= 26 and n <= 90: 
  print(f'{contador * chr(n)}')
  contador += 1
  n += 1
  if contador == (entrada + 1): 
    break
```

Dessa forma, você está restringindo a entrada até a quantidade máxima de letras do nosso alfabeto, ou seja 26, coletando as letras maiúsculas diretamente do unicode e printando da forma que o triangulo de letras vai crescendo.

```
Input: 

4



Output: 
A
BB
CCC
DDDD
```